# Sending an uploaded file through email without saving it first

Tags: javascript, file, email, upload

I am creating an application that allows a user to attach a file, type a message, then an email is sent using the PHP mailer plugin for wordpress.  I use javascript to get the file information from the upload html form and then php to send the email.  The plugin works when sending a file that is saved on the server in a specific location using this function:

```
$mail->AddAttachment("./new6.txt","attachment");
```

I was wondering if there is a way to email the file selected without having to save it to the server.  In other words, can a user select a file to upload, but send the file with this php function without saving it in a location to be retrieved?  I know there is a $_FILES array that you can get the file's information but will that file be able to be sent without it being saved somewhere first?  I'm guessing not since the whole point of the upload form is to "upload" it but just wondering if something could be done in javascript or something.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

You can't truly do that, but you could do this to get a close effect:

```
$filename = $_FILES['file_name']['tmp_name'];
$main->AddAttachment($filename, "attachment");

// Send the email... then:
unset($filename);
```

This adds the file as an attachment, sends the email, then deletes the file. The uploaded files in the `$_FILES` array will automatically be flushed out eventually, so I'm not sure if the `unset()` part even does anything significant, but it surely gets rid of the file.

Comment: the $filename  should come from server, but not from client machine.

Answer (score 0):

Without Saving file in Server, you can not attach it for mail.

```
1> Mailing function is executing in Server.
2> It is not possible from Server to get the absolute file path in client machine as in web, the client machines do not have any absolute address.
3> So the file is needed to be uploaded in server to get a real path for the file to have in attachment of Mail.
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a rather old question, but I think there's a rather useful answer that was never given. For the sake of those like me who happned along this question while searching for an answer to this question or similar, here you go.

When you upload a file to a server from a form, it's saved to the tmp directory automatically. Technically it's impossible to do anything with a form uploaded file without saving, because it's done for you automatically. However, because tmp is automatically cleaned on every reboot, this shouldn't be an issue in terms of building up too much backlog, if you either reboot often or set up a cron to delete your tmp directories contents regularly.

However, because it's saved to tmp, and because you can manipulate the file from there, it is possible to send the file without saving it for any form of longevity, and without actually writting anything to save it. Provided you perform all the necessary security checks on the file (verifying the contents, MIME-type and such that I won't go into now, but you can read up on how to do [here](https://webcheatsheet.com/php/file_upload.php)), you can use the following php function which I got from [Codexworld](https://www.codexworld.com/send-email-with-multiple-attachments-php/) and modified to use the tmp files. All you need to do is pass 
the parameters, and the $files is an array of files you've hopefully already vetted.

```
function multi_attach_mail($to, $subject, $message, $senderEmail, $senderName, $files = array()){ 

    $from = $senderName." <".$senderEmail.">";  
    $headers = "From: $from"; 

    // Boundary  
    $semi_rand = md5(time());  
    $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";  

    // Headers for attachment  
    $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" . " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";  

    // Multipart boundary  
    $message = "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"UTF-8\"\n" . 
    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $message . "\n\n";  

    // Preparing attachment 
    if(!empty($files)){ 
        for($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++){
            if(is_file($files[$i]["tmp_name"])){ 
                $tmp_name = basename($files[$i]["tmp_name"]);
                $file_name = $files[$i]["name"];
                $file_size = filesize($files[$i]["tmp_name"]); 

                $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n"; 
                $fp =    fopen($files[$i]["tmp_name"], "rb"); 
                $data =  fread($fp, $file_size); 
                fclose($fp); 
                $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data)); 
                $message .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$file_name."\"\n" .  
                "Content-Description: ".$file_name."\n" . 
                "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . " filename=\"".$file_name."\"; size=".$file_size.";\n" .  
                "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $data . "\n\n"; 
            }
        } 
    } 

    $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}--"; 
    $returnpath = "-f" . $senderEmail; 

    // Send email    
    $mail = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, $returnpath);  

    // Return true, if email sent, otherwise return false 
    if($mail){ 
        return true; 
    }else{ 
        return false; 
    } 
}
```